# Silverlight - Processing large text files

Tags: silverlight, text-files

I've been ask to port an application I made into some kind of a portal. The application basically reads, shows and process large files (5kb to 10~11mb each) containing text.

I've tried MVC with long loading times and performance issues.

I've been trying Silverlight since I've done some work with WPF in the past, and i'm struggling to find a solution to  quickly load this files into a RTB.

The issues i'm getting are mostly rendering issues which makes the browser to stop working until the rendering is done. Once the rendering is done the Silverlight app runs smoothly but every time the browser window is re-sized it seems the RTB start the text rendering all over again and the browser stops working until it renders everything.

So my question is : What are my main options to solve this issue since i need to be able to show and edit the files within the silverlight app.

here is some code i'm using to test loading and showing the text from a file

```
Run myRun1 = new Run();
myRun1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();

Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myRun1);

rtb_Log.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use webbrowser control also in in-browser apps in Silverlight 5.Beside this i would think about paging. I suppose, you do not need to show all 80k lines at once.

Comment: I still need to be able to navigate between them as if i'm using a text editor. Still i'll give it a look at paging. thanks for the reply